# Pass data and update fragments text/buttons on same host activity of NavigationUI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent

In the activity that hosts the navigation drawer I have the "Login" component on the menu which manages the google authentication. I want to propagate the user's info on another "Home" fragment and update its view with those infos.

**QUESTION**:
How do I pass data between **two fragments of the same host activity in NavigationUI** and how do I **update the TextView of the "Home" fragment for once** (since the view refreshes its default values all the time).

I tried with **intents** by specifying to the main activity the extras to receive so I can propagate them to the fragments, but it does not seem to work (getting the "*Cannot find activity*" error).
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have asked multiple questions trying to answer all of them.

1. How do I pass data between two fragments of the same host activity

if you are using ViewModel, use LiveData to communicate between two fragments. - suggested approach

if you are not using ViewModel then use the interface callback approach.

examples of the above two are mentioned here.

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

2. How do I pass data between two fragments of the same host activity using NavigationUI

in the nav_graph.xml you can find the arguments section where you can mention the arguments you want to pass.

An example of that is available in the given link
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

please add a comment if you want any more answers

Comment: Thank you man, it helped me so much. After some tries I was able to implement the message passing between fragments (with **arguments section**) and also with host activity (with **ViewModel**). The issue now is that every time I click on a fragment its view get refreshed and all the updates are lost. Is it something regarding fragments lifecycle methods? Should I use the savedIstanceState?

Comment: @tbekajon as we are talking about login here, why not save data in shared preferences and use that data in a fragment? 

every time you click on a fragment a new instance might be created which doesn't have old information